# Using Regular Expression in Php in case of checking phone number

Tags: php

I have a variable which has to allow only numbers , dashes and parenthesis, there is no particular length for phone number , And the validation must be done in php , no javascript allowed,

**EDIT** 
Just wanted to allow spaces too to the regular expressions....

Thanks

Comment: No particular length? so it isn't going to be a strictly US format?

Comment: @BenRoux and if not, which countries' formats are allowed? Samantha, your regex will probably have to try and match each country separately.

Comment: actually i want a variable which just needs to be validated, and the variable shouldnt contain anything other than dashes, paranthesis and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I am a bit confused about the question here, but I'll give it a shot and hopefully it gets you to where you need to be.

This will allow anything containing the specified characters. `(303)123-4567` will be allowed. As will `32084248())(21324234--234242-23-` (clearly not a phone number)

```
if( preg_match("/^[0-9() -]+$/", $number) {
    // Only numbers, parens and hypens allowed
}
```

If you want to make the regex a bit more strict, we can limit to US-style numbers:

```
if( preg_match("/^\d{0,3}-?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/", $number) {
    // US Phone number
}
```

This will only allow US style numbers with an optional country code.

Comment: hey ben can u tell how to allow spaces too in this

Comment: Sure thing. Which should I add it to? the first or second?

Comment: can u do  it for both ? but now priority is first one :)

Comment: THe first one is fixed. The regex there may look confusing, but all it is saying is only allow characters inside the brackets. Simply putting a space inside of them adds your solution